# Google play app signing key hash

Tags: android, google-play

I have opted for google play app signing and i understand that google changes the signing keys for the app and I found the Sha 1 certificate but couldnt find the keyhash .

How can i get the keyhash of my released app is there a way to extract it from the certificate?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**You can extract keyhash from the Sha1 certificate signature**. Key hashes are usually extracted in the following way:

```
public static String getKeyHash(final Context context) {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageInfo(context, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    if (packageInfo == null)
        return null;

    for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            return Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to get MessageDigest. signature=" + signature, e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can see that SHA-1 version of signature is Base64 encoded.

Under App Signing menu in Google play developer console, you will see Sha-1 certificate signature that looks like this:

```
SHA1: 3B:DA:A0:5B:4F:35:71:02:4E:27:22:B9:AC:B2:77:2F:9D:A9:9B:D9
```

Basically, what you have to do is to change this into a byte array and Base64 encode that byte array. You can do something like:

```
byte[] sha1 = {
    0x3B, (byte)0xDA, (byte)0xA0, 0x5B, 0x4F, 0x35, 0x71, 0x02, 0x4E, 0x27, 0x22, (byte)0xB9, (byte)0xAc, (byte)0xB2, 0x77, 0x2F, (byte)0x9D, (byte)0xA9, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0xD9
};
Log.e("keyhash", Base64.encodeToString(sha1, Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

You can register this keyhash to facebook android login settings or wherever you like.

Comment: You also get this hash value in an error message from facebook when logging in on the right account from the app.  Whats interesting is that though the hashes seem to be visually the same, when I programmatically generate it using the above method it worked, where as visually typing it in did not.

Comment: the next comment is simpler, so I downvoted this one

Comment: @GonzaloSerrano but mine is platform-independent? ><

Comment: @CoderSpinoza the other one works in any UNIX (Linux, MacOS)

Comment: You could use an online tool like: https://cryptii.com/base64-to-hex. Set it to ENCODE and put HEX in the left and get HASHKEY on the right

Answer (score 259):

You can convert SHA-1 hash in hex format (as found in Play console, see Release management -> App Signing) into base64 hash using next command:

```
echo 33:4E:48:84:19:50:3A:1F:63:A6:0F:F6:A1:C2:31:E5:01:38:55:2E | xxd -r -p | openssl base64
```

Output:

```
M05IhBlQOh9jpg/2ocIx5QE4VS4=
```

This hash can be used for example when setting up Facebook app.

Comment: works on git bash in windows. you might need to install openssl. https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads

Comment: this is the best answer on Stackoverflow

Comment: Does this hash key change on every bundle upload? In that case one has to go to Facebook console and manually update has too

Comment: @helloworld no, it remains same.

Answer (score 12):

The **easiest** way would be to copy Facebook's error message and **copy the keyhash they were expecting to get from there.**

Just make sure you are using your Google Play downloaded app :)[image]

Answer (score 1):

> echo "App signing key generate by google in play console" | xxd -r -p | "openssl path" base64

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with a command. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

firstly required same important tools

1.OpenSSl: intall in your pc [Download Here](https://www.openssl.org/)
2.Install Java Programm in your Pc Or Laptop [Download Now](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html)

Simply Run The commond promt
1.Go to your directory
2.cd Program Files
3.select where java programm you have installed
then copy all directory without c drive and past the directory in commond promt with cd
4.keytool -exportcert -alias gci -keystore D:\folder name where place your release key |C:\openssl\bin\openssl sha1 -binary |C:\openssl\bin\openssl base64

[for more information Visit here](https://thekingofviral.com/how-to-generate-google-play-app-signing-key-hash-2021/)