# facebook sign in react native not working if facebook app is installed

Tags: react-native-fbsdk

I am using react-native-fbsdk. it is working fine if facebook app is not installed. but it is not working if facebook app is installed on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/635).  Make sure your app is correctly signed, make sure [your key is correctly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355452/google-play-app-signing-key-hash/44448437#44448437).  You also might want to try correctly formatting your key [this way](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/633#issuecomment-554335094) if you don't want to use the command line.  There is still an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/633) on GitHub for this exact problem, and you might want to look at some of the solutions there.  You can also refrence the [quick start guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started), there is a bit of help there on this exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

These AppDelegate.m changes solved my issue!

https://dev.to/aneeqakhan/how-to-add-fb-sdk-in-react-native-project-109d

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have inserted the signed certs and I have developed a react-native app in which it didn't allow users to use facebook login because, i have inserted invalid certs and it all went wrong. So make sure that you have inserted the valid certs

Thank you for reading