# azure signaturehash rejects my Base64 encoded SHA1 hash from debug.keystore

Tags: android, azure, xamarin

I try to authentificate my xamarin app on azure.

To create the Base64 encoded SHA1 hash for my debug.keystore i used the suggested command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I get a result but it has 32 characters and gets rejected from azures frontend validation with the message:

> The signature hash must be a Base64 encoded SHA1 hash.

If i use the placeholder or a substring of my hash it is working

```
2pmj9i4rSx0yEb/viWBYkE/ZQrk=       <- `Example from Azure (is working)`
aPz8/NARbPz8pPzg/Iz9aPz8NCg=       <- `some working example generated by me`
CAY/Pz8/NARbPz8pPzg/Iz9aPz8NCg==   <- `My base64 (is not working)`
```

it seems like that azure needs always 28 characters but my generated base74 has 32...

I wasted 20 hours on this problem but diddnt find any solution.

Answer (score 15):

I just encountered this same issue. AzureAd does not seem to want    openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

I had to open up gradle on android/app/build.gradle

open up    app/tasks/android -> signingReport

grab the sha1 from there in the    form of xx:xx:xx...xx:xx

convert to base 64 here:    https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex

hope this helps

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47609031/298288 for a purely local version to convert to base64

Answer (score 3):

Not enough rep to comment on Jorge Luiz's post, but I had to complete an additional step to make this method work. My full solution was this:

- Go to settings (File -> Settings)
- Go to the Experimental tab
- Under Gradle, disable `Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync`

Then follow the steps as in Jorge's post, which I will recap here. If the task does not appear, you may need to sync your gradle files again. You can find this option under File -> Sync project with gradle files. Then follow these steps:

- Open the Gradle view (View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle)
- Locate the `signingReport` task (`<projectname>(/app)/Tasks/android/signingReport`)
- Double click, or right click and select run

The Run tab should automatically open, then from there you:

- Copy the SHA1 HEX value in the form XX:XX:XX...
- Convert it to base64 using a tool like https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex

Answer (score 1):

On Android Studio go to *View->Tool Windows->Gradle*.

On the *Gradle* tab go to *YOURPROJECTNAME->Tasks->android->signingReport*.

Right-click on *signingReport* and left-click on *'Run YOURPROJECTNAME [signingReport]'*.

Get the *SHA1* from the *Run tab* generated output on the IDE bottom in the form of *xx:xx:xx...xx:xx*.

Convert to *base 64* here: https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex

Answer (score 1):

I had the same failure, so a couple of things helped:

## PowerShell

If you run this from PowerShell, be sure to change %HOMEPATH% to $env:HOMEPATH like so:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore $env:HOMEPATH\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

## Base64

I tried to use `base64` from my Git installation to encode it but it didn't like that version. You can add your Windows Git path to the PATH environment to use the git versions of these tools:

PowerShell: `$env:path += "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\`

Command Prompt: `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\`

Then use openssl as in the example. This time from the command prompt (not PowerShell):

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

The final example worked for me on Azure.

Comment: this worked (as of Oct, 2023). Key was not to use Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

For me using Xamarin.Forms I needed another workaround to get the SHA1 out of the certificate:

```
.\keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android
```

then convert the HEX values here: https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin or .NET MAUI and got this issue on Azure Active Directory,
Make sure to generate the key using the following command

```
keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\{YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE}\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

This will list all the details including the fingerprints in the HEX format for you for the SHA1
for example

```
...
Valid from: Sat May 28 00:12:26 GST 2022 until: Mon May 20 00:12:26 GST 2052
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: 0B:08:00:00:00:0D:CC:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
...
```

Copy the value of the SHA1 format and as mentioned in the comment of *Sam Svindland* and paste it in:
https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex
And click **Convert to Base64**, then put the generated value in Azure AD.
That worked very well for me

Answer (score 0):

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Running the command from the terminal window in VS Code got me the same error.

Running the command from the command prompt Azure AD accepted the result.